# Word 2007 multipage tiff picture insert

Tags: microsoft-word, tiff

I have a multipage TIFF file I need to use in Word 2007.  Problem is I can only figure out how to insert the first page the multipage TIFF file.  Does Word have the ability to let me select which page of the mulipage tiff I want to insert or do I have to break the TIFF file up (which would be a pain)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if Word can do it, but Irfanview has an option to extract multiple pages from a multipage tiff.  I just used that to break up the whole document into its individual pages and went from there.